# Help identify the chords in bar 1,5,6 of schubert waltz op9 no31

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

Please help identity the chords. I couldn’t form a chord!

I [image]

Comment: Sorry, but questions such as this are disallowed for this site. Please read the Help Centre to understand how you could re-phrase the question so it doen't get closed.

Comment: In addition to @Tim's comment that questions like "what chord is this" are off topic here, just checking to clarify if this is part of a class homework assignment. Homework assistance is also off-topic here. If you're asking for some other reason, including that in your question will help get the best answers for you.

Comment: Welcome! I wonder whether you're trouble is that there are "so many notes" in those measures, and how to simplify them down to chords. I think this can be a valid question, but to get the right answer, please use the "Edit" button to explain a bit more about the trouble you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points that might help clear up confusion:

- A measure might contain more than one chord.
- A chord might be "spread out" across multiple octaves or beats. For instance, the first beat has two different Es and two Gs in different octaves, and there's a C falling on the second half of the beat. These could all be consolidated and considered together.
- There might be "extra notes" that don't belong to a chord. If we're trying to find a "simple," broad analysis, we can ignore these and look for the "main idea" of the chord.

  - For instance, in m. 1, the very first beat has all the notes for a nice C major triad. These are also the notes of beat three. Beat two is simply made of some half-step "neighbors" of these notes; it's just a type of ornamentation. We move onto these neighbors and then right back onto CM; nothing significant has happened; for basic analytical purposes we can ignore the ornament and just call the measure CM.
  - Think about this idea and look at mm. 5 and 6 as if they were one measure.